# How to align a label text in VS2012?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, label, text-align

I clicked on a label, searched in the properties and couldn't find how to align the text to right. The option under "Paragraph" --> "Text alignment" is greyed out.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the   **HorizontalAlignment** to **Center**,

```
 <sdk:Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="label1" Width="120" />
```

Comment: I set the HorizontalAlignment to Right then repositioned my textbox and the text is now right aligned. Thanks !